# 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute '_id'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a tensorflow model which takes 3 images as an input and gives 3 output embedding for each input image and further want to continue training.
The part of code is given below:

```
def tripler_trainer(input_shape=(112,112,3)):
    anchor_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    positive_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    negative_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

    embedder = inner_model(act_func='relu', input_shape=(112,112,3)  # return embedding of shape(1,128)

    anchor_embedding = embedder(anchor_input)
    positive_embedding = embedder(positive_input)
    negative_embedding = embedder(negative_input)
    outer_network = Model(inputs=(anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input),
                          outputs=(anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding))
    return outer_network

def triplet_loss(triplets, margin=0.20):
    triplet_loss = 0
    anchor = triplets[0]
    positive = triplets[1]
    negative = triplets[2]

    anchor = tf.math.l2_normalize(anchor, axis=None, epsilon=1e-12, name=None, dim=None)
    positive = tf.math.l2_normalize(positive, axis=None, epsilon=1e-12, name=None, dim=None)
    negative = tf.math.l2_normalize(negative, axis=None, epsilon=1e-12, name=None, dim=None)
    # print(anchor)

    anchor_pos_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor - positive)))
    anchor_neg_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor - negative)))

    if anchor_pos_dist <= anchor_neg_dist <= (anchor_pos_dist + margin):
        triplet_loss = np.max(((anchor_pos_dist - anchor_neg_dist) + margin), 0)

    return triplet_loss

epochs = 100
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

train_data_util_instance = TripletFormulator(data_path_dictionary=data_path, batch=4)  # data path contains 3 subfolders containing images of different class
train_data_array_dict, data_count = train_data_util_instance.data_loader()
majority_class = max(data_count, key=data_count.get)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for majority_class_batch in train_data_array_dict[majority_class]:
        train_batch_dict = {}
        train_batch_dict['class A'] = next(iter(train_data_array_dict['A']))
        train_batch_dict['class B'] = next(iter(train_data_array_dict['B']))
        train_batch_dict['class C'] = majority_class_batch
        train_triplets = train_data_util_instance.triplet_generator(train_batch_dict)  # Batch of triplets. with each instance containing 3 images.
         
        for triplets in train_triplets:
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                 logits = self.model([tf.reshape(triplets[0], [-1, 112, 112, 3]),
                                      tf.reshape(triplets[1], [-1, 112, 112, 3]),
                                      tf.reshape(triplets[2], [-1, 112, 112, 3])], training=True)
                 loss_value = triplet_loss(triplets=logits, alpha=0.2)
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.model.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_weights))
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
    File "C:/Users/G5205GK/Desktop/Working Dir/code/con_learning/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/G5205GK/Desktop/Working Dir/code/con_learning/main.py", line 31, in main
    training_instance.train()
  File "C:\Users\G5205GK\Desktop\Working Dir\code\con_learning\train.py", line 45, in train
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.model.trainable_weights)
  File "C:\Users\G5205GK\Anaconda3\envs\my_gpu_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py", line 1074, in gradient
    flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(
  File "C:\Users\G5205GK\Anaconda3\envs\my_gpu_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py", line 71, in imperative_grad
    return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute '_id'
```

Can any one please suggest where the problem is. Also the code provided, is simplified for stack overflow. so it may have syntax issue.

Also, the code works upto line where loss is calculated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I  invalidated the cache now I am getting a different error-
raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." %
TypeError: Cannot convert value 0 to a TensorFlow DType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Tensorflow operations when calculating the loss of your model. Try replacing `np.max`  with `tf.math.reduce_max`:

```py
triplet_loss = tf.math.reduce_max(((anchor_pos_dist - anchor_neg_dist) + margin), 0)
```

Comment: Hello @AlnoeTogether. Thanks once again for helping me for similar code. I was able to solve the 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute '_id' issue. Also your method is also working great. Just one update, the value should be in a list.

But now I am getting another error which is - raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." % TypeError: Cannot convert value 0 to a TensorFlow DType

Comment: I found a way to handle this new error. It seems the loss values need to be converted to tf.dtypes. I was able to do it by converting the loss values to tf.constant(loss_value).

Can there be any other way of handeling this problem?